# Software installation with GUI package installer using sudo permission

Tags: linux, sudo

I have the sudo permission, and I can install any software using the CLI.
But I want to know that whether `sudo` works with package installers in GUI mode.

For example I have a `.chm` file and I want to open it with a mouse click, but `chmviewer` is not installed. So some prompt appears to search on net and by clicking on that pop-up it has suggested some packages e.g `kchmviewer`. But when I clicked on `<install>` it pops-up asking for the root password, which I don't have.

Is there a way to install software in GUI mode when you have sudo permission, but not the root password?
Just for curiosity I want to know how to use `sudo` with a GUI installation mode.

<sub>BTW: I have already installed `kchmviewer` from command line :)</sub>

Comment: as @andrewsomething said on [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/using-sudo-on-gui-applications) : "Graphical programs should not be run with sudo. The correct way is to use kdesudo in KDE for running GUI programs as root, or gksu in GNOME."

Comment: The program *should* let you choose your own method for becoming root: su, sudo or some other option (possibly via a GUI prompt). It's not a matter of using sudo with a GUI installation mode, but rather of using sudo with this particular application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know is to run the GUI application with root (sudo) privileges. So, if you do something like `sudo dolphin` or whatever is your file manager of choice, than when you click on an 'unknown' file type and an install is proposed you already have the root privileges inherited from the file manager window. However running GUI file managers with root privileges is not recommended for security reasons.

Or, you could run your GUI installer directly with sudo, like `sudo your_gui_package_manager_application` (ie. `sudo sulfur` if you are on Sabayon).

I am not sure, but I think you can do/run sudo something directly from your favorite launcher (Gnome-do, krunner, everything-starter, etc.).

Comment: @ Patkos Csaba thanks. i used sudo nautius and it worked for me.

Comment: I wasted 20 minutes after i found your solution. Thanks