# Being root without asking for the password in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to write a script which runs "chrome" as root without getting password from the users. Users should not know the password,they also should not see the password,if they open the script (if the root password is needed to be written into script,we need to encrypt it)
How can be possible that ? I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493464/changing-unix-user-in-a-shell-script) one and it didn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
"right here i need to be root"
chrome -P http://www.google.com.tr & sleep 4
```

Comment: Chrome?  As root?  I hope you have good backups...  (And this sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What *problem* are you trying to solve by running Chrome as root?)

Comment: The program you're looking for is called `sudo`.  But if you allow people to run chrome as root then they may easily be able to break out and get an interactive shell, and so do _anything_ on your machine.   Be VERY careful!  Maybe think about how to solve your problem in another way that doesn't involve such a security risk.

Comment: What's the aim of this action?

Comment: You could just save everyone's time (users, disgruntled employees, hackers, etc.) and add `%users ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in sudoers; users will be able to run chrome as root, and anything else they can start from chrome as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Use sudo. Add a rule in the sudoers file to allow users to run a specific command or script as root.

If you want to abstract the use of sudo to the users, have a normal script call sudo on behalf of the user.

What worries me here though is the use of chrome as root. I don't need to ask why, but keep in mind that it's a security risk. Whatever you do you should consider using a dedicated, non-privileged user. If you need some of root's capabilities, see linux capabilities (`man 7 capabilities`) to give only the required superuser permissions to your chrome user.

Answer (score 0):

If the script launches a graphical application, then it should not be run with `sudo`. See for example:

[Why shouldn't sudo be used to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

[using sudo on GUI applications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/using-sudo-on-gui-applications/3071#3071)

I can't recommend running chrome as root(!), but in principle, to launch a graphical application as root without logging in as root, you should use `pkexec`. As explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/332847/527764) it should be enough to set the necessary environment variables in the command

```
 pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY ./your-script
```

The user will be prompted for their own password. Strictly speaking though (or if this fails), you should make a policy file. See [`man pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pkexec.1.html) and more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313828/why-is-pkexec-preferred-over-gksudo-for-graphical-applications) and specifically about scripts [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288087/can-i-use-pkexec-in-a-python-script-or-a-desktop-file)

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's a pretty bad idea as you will have to set your parrword in clear in you script.

That's not a good point in security but you can do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

set pass "YOUR_PASSWORD"

sudo your_command

expect "Password"
send "$pass\r"
```

But why not doing a chmod u+s ?

Comment: suid doesn't work on scripts for security reason - there is a race condition you cannot avoid that could allow users running anything as root.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me, that what you actually want, is set the UID of the executed process, rather than running the process under a specific user.

Whay you might want instead, is setting the SUID of the program correctly as [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SUID).

Short example:

Suppose your program `run` is owned by root (user and group):

```
$ chmod u+s run
$ ls -l run
-rwsrwxr-x. 1 root root 0 Aug  5 15:08 run*
```

Note the 's' in the executable bit in the user block.
Now, when executed by someone else, the process will be run as the user to which this file belongs to, which is root.

**Note:** as Doug O'Neal has brought up correctly, this doesn't work on any sort of interpreted language on Linux! *(More details on that [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html))* You'd need to make a small wrapper program in C and compile it, for instance.

Comment: The suid bit is not honored on shell scripts.

Comment: @DougO'Neal doh'! Damn! I completely forgot standard linux safeties. Thanks for bringing it up, dude.